# How to update DataRowView value?

Tags: c#, datalist, datarowview

I created a prize list and language option. I want to change some prize's picture. My web site is loading default Turkish language, if selected 
other language, i will send "&dl=en" QueryString.

Here's my code;

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    var asd  = e.Item.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
    var asde = e.Item.FindControl("Image2") as Image;
    var drw  = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
    string a = drw["OdulID"].ToString();

    var listColumns  = new List<int>() { 121, 122, 123, 125, 128 };
    var rowsToUpdate = new List<DataRowView>();

    if (Request.QueryString["dl"] == "tr" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["dl"]))
        asd.ImageUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webservis"] + @"resimGoster.aspx?Istek=Odul&ID=" + a + "&Resim=Resim";
    else foreach (DataRowView row in drw.DataView)
    {
        if (lstColumns.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(row["OdulID"])))
            rowsToUpdate.Add(row);          
    }
    foreach (DataRowView row in rowsToUpdate)
        asd.ImageUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webservis"] + @"resimGoster.aspx?Istek=Odul&ID=" + row["OdulID"] + "&Resim=Resim";
}
```

All of prize image comes 128.prize's image. How can i solve it. I just want to change the picture of 5 (121, 122, 123, 125, 128)ID  prizes.

Comment: You seriously need better variable names. `asd` and `a` don't help at all, and `drw` barely helps.

Comment: @AustinWBryan, very good programmers do not fit in variable names :)

Answer (score 0):

I think change "+ row["OdulID"] +" ,  "+row+"

```
foreach (DataRowView row in rowsToUpdate)
{
      asd.ImageUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webservis"] + @"resimGoster.aspx?Istek=Odul&ID=" + row + "&Resim=Resim"; 
}
```